# Where is cookiepath of tor?

Tags: relays, configuration, circuit

I am working on tools for change identity of tor every 3 minutes.
But it require a cookie path of tor.
I follow this one https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/4881 but didn't find its yet.

Thank for support.

Comment: Why changing identity every 3mins? it's too often and probably bad both for you and network... Tor does that for you every 10mins. see [For how long does a circuit stay alive?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/262/for-how-long-does-a-circuit-stay-alive)

Answer (score 3):

By default Tor will not require authentication from local users. Have you enabled cookie authentication in torrc? If you have, Tor will write the cookie in the file control_auth_cookie in the Tor data directory: http://archives.seul.org/or/talk/Jan-2009/msg00071.html