# What does Tor do with streams?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit, stream-isolation

I am a bit confused about handling streams in Tor. When we visit a website like Youtube the browser sends more than 100 requests to more than 20 different hosts. If we consider each request is for a TCP connection and, for the sake of anonymity, we cannot attach two streams to the same circuit, we need a bunch of circuits just for visiting a website.

I do  not know what Tor actually does with streams.
Are all streams for a website attached to the same circuit?
or are they attached to distinct circuits?
or Can we reuse circuits?, I mean, does Tor attach several streams to the same circuit?

Comment: Also, your browser will already multiplex several requests into a single TCP connection (HTTP keep-alive, etc.)

Comment: Hi there; thanks for joining Tor.SE. Just a quick note: The answer feature is only for answers (not comments). In future, please use the comments feature for non-answers. For more info, on answering question see "[How do I write a good answer?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" in the help center (I've gone ahead and moved your answer to a comment this time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tor puts many streams onto a single circuit.  If possible, the same circuit is used for up to 10 minutes -- see [For how long does a circuit stay alive?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/262/for-how-long-does-a-circuit-stay-alive/270#270) for some details.

Accordingly, if you visit a website and it takes a hundred http connections to fetch it all, Tor will use the same circuit for all of that.  If you stay on the website for a while and load more things, then after a while you'll move to a new circuit for your requests.